# How to fix .htaccess with mod_rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use this .htaccess:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#redirect to trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I use the next code inside the URLManager (yii2 framework):

```
   'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                '<username:\w+>'=>'site/user',
            ],
```

I found that dynamic css and js doesn't load. I know that problem in the line with my redirect rule. But how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reorder your directives like this:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine On

#redirect to trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: **doesn't work** type comment is of not much use. What URL did you enter in browser and what problem did you get. What is exact URL of dynamic CSS that doesn't load?